# How to get the OriginURL using morgan and winston.js format in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, morgan, winstone

I'm trying to get the originalURL from the message attribute using winston.js and morgan in a nodejs project (the code):

winstone.je

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, label, printf } = format;

const myFormat = printf(({ level, message, label, timestamp }) => {
  return `${timestamp}  ${level}: ${message}`;
});

const logger = createLogger({
  format: combine(
    label({ label: 'right meow!' }),
    timestamp(),
    myFormat
  ),
  transports: [new transports.Console()]
});
```

app.js

```
app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: winston.stream }));
```

the output of is :

```
2019-03-12T13:35:50.112Z : ::1 - - [12/Mar/2019:13:35:50 +0000] "GET /api/bar/origin/000a  HTTP/1.1"
```

what I'm looking for is to get just this part : "GET /api/bar/origin/000a  HTTP/1.1" without using substring or slice on the message attribute, Is there a way the get origineURL from myFormat const please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on the  [Morgan documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) you can change the output format either using a predefined format (`combined`, `tiny`, ...) or make your own which should look like `app.use(morgan(':method :url HTTP/:http-version', { stream: winston.stream }));`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did what u suggested but nothing happened, the change must be done to winston.js I think to controle the output of the console

Comment: Ah, Ok I got it, but another question pleasr is there a way to know the executed time of the request please ?

Comment: if you add `:response-time ms` to your `morgan()` it should do what you want :)

Comment: yes I did that thanks, is there a way to take args from the URL ?

Comment: still based on the documentation, you can create `morgan-token`  [like this](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#use-custom-token-formats) giving you the possibility to log url parameters.

Comment: its not easy this time, the args are passed in the controller, how i can match between app.js and ctr ?